# Peeking top of stack causing out of bounds exception

Tags: java, stack

Before I begin, I apologize if this is difficult to read, its from a book and I'm not allowed to change it much. I have to implement a method called peek() that checks the top of the stack, and then is displayed.

[image]

I have reset() and size() working, but why is peek() not working?

```
interface ISimpleStack {

  // Push a character onto the stack.
  void push(char ch);

  // Pop a character from the stack.
  char pop();

  // Return true if the stack is empty.
  boolean isEmpty();

  // Return true if the stack is full.
  boolean isFull();

  void reset();

  char peek();

  int size();
}

// A fixed-length stack for characters.
class FixedLengthStack implements ISimpleStack {
  private char[] data; // this array holds the stack
  private int tos; // index of top of stack

  // Construct an empty stack given its size.
  FixedLengthStack(int size) {
    data = new char[size]; // create the array to hold the stack
    tos = 0;
  }

  // Construct a stack from a stack.
  FixedLengthStack(FixedLengthStack otherStack) {
    // size of new stack equals that of otherStack
    data = new char[otherStack.data.length];

    // set tos to the same position
    tos = otherStack.tos;

    // copy the contents
    for(int i = 0; i < tos; i++)
      data[i] = otherStack.data[i];
  }

  // Construct a stack with initial values.
  FixedLengthStack(char[] chrs) {
    // create the array to hold the initial values
    data = new char[chrs.length];
    tos = 0;

    // initialize the stack by pushing the contents
    // of chrs onto it
    for(char ch : chrs)
      push(ch);
  }

  // Push a character onto the stack.
  public void push(char ch) {
    if(isFull()) {
      System.out.println(" -- Stack is full.");
      return;
    }

    data[tos] = ch;
    tos++;
  }

  // Pop a character from the stack.
  public char pop() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(" -- Stack is empty.");
      return (char) 0; // a placeholder value
    }

    tos--;
    return data[tos];
  }

  // Return true if the stack is empty.
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return tos==0;
  }

  // Return true if the stack is full.
  public boolean isFull() {
    return tos==data.length;
  }

  public void reset() {
      tos = 0;
  }

  public char peek() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(" -- Stack is empty.");
      return (char) 0; // a placeholder value
    }

    return data[tos];
  }

  public int size() {
      int size = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i <= tos; i++){
         size = i;
      }
      System.out.println("Size of stack is: " + size);
      return size;
  }
}

// A growable stack for characters.
class DynamicStack implements ISimpleStack {
  private char[] data; // this array holds the stack
  private int tos; // index of top of stack

  // Construct an empty stack given its size.
  DynamicStack(int size) {
    data = new char[size]; // create the array to hold the stack
    tos = 0;
  }

  // Construct a stack from a stack.
  DynamicStack(DynamicStack otherStack) {
    // size of new stack equals that of otherStack
    data = new char[otherStack.data.length];

    // set tos to the same position
    tos = otherStack.tos;

    // copy the contents
    for(int i = 0; i < tos; i++)
      data[i] = otherStack.data[i];
  }

  // Construct a stack with initial values.
  DynamicStack(char[] chrs) {
    // create the array to hold the initial values
    data = new char[chrs.length];
    tos = 0;

    // initialize the stack by pushing the contents
    // of chrs onto it
    for(char ch : chrs)
      push(ch);
  }

  // Push a character onto the stack.
  public void push(char ch) {

    // if there is no more room in the array,
    // expand the size of the stack
    if(tos == data.length) {
      // double the size of the existing array
      char[] t = new char[data.length * 2];

      // copy the contents of the stack into the larger array
      for(int i = 0; i < tos; i++)
        t[i] = data[i];

      // set data to refer to the new array
      data = t;
    }

    data[tos] = ch;
    tos++;
  }

  // Pop a character from the stack.
  public char pop() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(" -- Stack is empty.");
      return (char) 0; // a placeholder value
    }

    tos--;
    return data[tos];
  }

  // Return true if the stack is empty.
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return tos==0;
  }

  // Return true if the stack is full. For DynamicStack,
  // this method always returns false.
  public boolean isFull() {
    return false;
  }

  public void reset() {
      tos = 0;
  }

  public char peek() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(" -- Stack is empty.");
      return (char) 0; // a placeholder value
    }

    return data[tos];
  }

  public int size() {
      int size = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i <= tos; i++){
         size = i;
      }
      System.out.println("Size of stack is: " + size);
      return size;
  }
}

// Demonstrate ISimpleStack.
class ISimpleStackDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    char ch;

    // create an ISimpleStack interface variable
    ISimpleStack iStack;

    // Now, construct a FixedLengthStack and a DynamicStack
    FixedLengthStack fixedStack = new FixedLengthStack(10);
    DynamicStack dynStack = new DynamicStack(5);

    // first, use fixedStack through iStack
    iStack = fixedStack;

    // push characters onto fixedStack
    for(i = 0; !iStack.isFull(); i++)
      iStack.push((char) ('A'+i));

    iStack.size();

    System.out.print("Top of fixedStack: ");
    while(!iStack.isEmpty()) {
      ch = iStack.peek();
      System.out.print(ch);
    }

    // pop characters off fixedStack
    System.out.print("Contents of fixedStack: ");
    while(!iStack.isEmpty()) {
      ch = iStack.pop();
      System.out.print(ch);
    }

    System.out.print("\nContents of fixedStack after reset: ");
    iStack.reset();
      ch = iStack.pop();
      System.out.print(ch);
    System.out.println();

    // next, use dynStack through iStack
    iStack = dynStack;

    // push A through Z onto dynStack
    // this will result in three increases in its size
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
      iStack.push((char) ('A'+i));

    iStack.size();
    // pop characters off dynStack
    System.out.print("Contents of dynStack: ");
    while(!iStack.isEmpty()) {
      ch = iStack.pop();
      System.out.print(ch);
    }
    System.out.print("\nContents of dynStack after reset: ");
    iStack.reset();
      ch = iStack.pop();
      System.out.print(ch);
  }
}
```

Comment: If the array is 0 based, and you increment tos after a push, then it will be beyond the end of the array, non? You need to peek at data[data.length - 1].

Comment: Output: http://pastebin.com/Mi1vBfSY

This stopped the error, but it isn't displaying the second one.

Comment: Did you make the same change? The variable tos is the _size_ of the stack, but to find the character that is in the last position you must look at `data[tos - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code in the example, making the following change to peek() solves the output issue noted in the 2nd example in the paste bin. It is the same issue as would occur in the FixedLengthStack. In fact, a slightly better implementation would probably be to have an abstract Stack class that implemented size(), reset(), pop(), (which, btw, should probably set the array to an empty array as well), and peek().

```
@Override
public char peek()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(" -- Stack is empty.");
        return (char) 0; // a placeholder value
    }

    return data[tos - 1];
}
```